# Clang error:failed with exitcode 1(use -v to see invocation)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to develop an application in xcode using objective c  with SUP backend.When I builded my project I got an error like

> Ld /Users/chairman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/New_App-brpimxjxwxsuimcjcfjjrmpnextw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/New_App.app/New_App normal i386
>       cd /Users/chairman/Desktop/New_App/New_App
>       setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
>       setenv PATH "/Users/chairman/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/chairman/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Users/chairman/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Users/chairman/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/chairman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/New_App-brpimxjxwxsuimcjcfjjrmpnextw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/chairman/Desktop/New_App/New_App/../../MAC_IOS/importing_Libraries/Libraries/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/chairman/Desktop/New_App/New_App/../../MAC_IOS/importing_Libraries/Libraries/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/chairman/Desktop/New_App/New_App/../../MAC_IOS/importing_Libraries/Libraries/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/chairman/Desktop/New_App/New_App/../../MAC_IOS/importing_Libraries/Libraries/Release-iphonesimulator -L/Users/chairman/Desktop/New_App/New_App/../../New_App_Data/importing_Libraries/Libraries/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/chairman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/New_App-brpimxjxwxsuimcjcfjjrmpnextw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/chairman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/New_App-brpimxjxwxsuimcjcfjjrmpnextw/Build/Intermediates/New_App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/New_App.build/Objects-normal/i386/New_App.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -lstdc++.6 -lz.1.2.5 -licucore.A -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreFoundation -framework AddressBook -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/chairman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/New_App-brpimxjxwxsuimcjcfjjrmpnextw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/New_App.app/New_App
>
> ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_dev_BhaskarG_com_igate_shipping_v1KeyGenerator._remoteId in /Users/chairman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/New_App-brpimxjxwxsuimcjcfjjrmpnextw/Build/Intermediates/New_App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/New_App.build/Objects-normal/i386/dev_BhaskarG_com_igate_shipping_v1KeyGenerator.o and /Users/chairman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/New_App-brpimxjxwxsuimcjcfjjrmpnextw/Build/Intermediates/New_App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/New_App.build/Objects-normal/i386/dev_BhaskarG_com_igate_shipping_v1KeyGenerator copy.o for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can anyone please help me in solving this?

Comment: Nope, not until you find the *real* error message.  Check the build logs (last button on the top of the left pane of Xcode)

Comment: There are two warnings with that error like
1.Receiver 'NSConnection' is a forward class and curresponding @interface may not exist 
2.class method +prepareStatement : not found(return type defaults to id)
and the error is like 
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$.....for architecture i386

Comment: You should not leave warnings like that.  However, the error is the relevant issue here, edit your question with the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate symbol means you have the same symbol (class, variable, etc) defined in two places in your project (or its included libraries).

Look at the error messages...it looks like you've included the same file in your project twice:

dev_BhaskarG_com_igate_shipping_v1KeyGenerator
dev_BhaskarG_com_igate_shipping_v1KeyGenerator copy

Comment: We got the generated code from some others,and we tried removing dev_BhaskarG_com_igate_shipping_v1KeyGenerator copy.h file then it is showing so many errors like undefined symbol for architecture i386: 
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MBOLogger" referenced from:
 _objc_class_ref in CallbackHandler.o 
_objc_class_ref in New_App.o
 _objc_class_ref in --Shipping_v1_subscription_status.o

Comment: That's a different problem.  You can't have both files.  That's the end of the story.